# Struggling with background for my android app

Tags: android, xml, background

I am building an android app and been following a particular design on [this link](https://dribbble.com/shots/2481960-Currency-Converter)

This is the design I have build so far

[image]

I have been trying to make a background similar to the one in the link. Which is transparent. Or I don't know what it's called.

Could someone help me provide any details to it? What it is called and how can I make one?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like in the link it is just a blurred image. You can create on yourself and set it as background.

Comment: What if I want to create it using xml? is that possible?

Comment: Create the image and put it into the drawable folder. Then add android:background="@drawable/yourimagename" to your background view in xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for make your background transparent

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```